# Transforming a dictionary of lists to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Let's say that I have a dictionary that looks something like this:
`{'blue': [1,2,3], 'red' : [1,3]}`
I would like to transform this into a dataframe of two columns in which one column is the color name (red or blue) and the other is the value. Perhaps, something like this:

```
blue    1
blue    2
blue    3
red     1
red     3
```

Is there a short way in doing so? I have checked ways of transferring dictionaries into dataframe but none of them talked about the case in which values are lists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way would be to transform your dict into the list of tuples before giving it to `pd.DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'blue': [1,2,3], 'red' : [1,3]}

lst = [(k, i) for k, v in d.items() for i in v]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

df
       0    1
0   blue    1
1   blue    2
2   blue    3
3   red     1
4   red     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html):

```
d = {'blue': [1,2,3], 'red' : [1,3]}
s = pd.concat([pd.Series(v, index=np.repeat(k, len(v))) for k,v in d.items()])

print(s)
blue    1
blue    2
blue    3
red     1
red     3
dtype: int64
```